# Session leakage

Tags: security-token-service, session, token, cookie

I use SharePoint to host our website on the internet. Site users use Form-based authentication to log in.

These past few days, the site has a very weird issue with people logging in and being redirected to other random peoples' profiles and details.

Here is what I have tried so far to trouble-shoot the issue:

- Contacted the users to check if there is any chance of someone else having used their PC before they logged in. Most Users say they used a private device and also don’t know the user whose profile they see.
- Tried looking at default ULS logs, but did not see anything suspicious, except that the two people logged in at about the same times.
- Tried generating some logs from code in login and profile webparts into an SQL data base and also to ULS, the logs show that in the error instances, the session cookies and fedauth cookies get mixed up in different ways.
- > Sometimes, the session cookie changes to a different user’s session cookie.
- > Sometimes, there is a single fedauth cookie at login time, but in later requests two fedauth cookies show up in each request, one from the user’s own original session, and other from the different session, whose profile is seen.
- > Sometimes, both of these issues happen at once.
- I am also using load-balancing hardware to forward requests based on cookies, to different servers. So I tried routing the user directly to a single portal server. The issue still persisted.
- I also have two web front-end servers that are part of the same farm, so I tried shutting one server down, to narrow down the issue. Issue still persists.
- I have also tried changing various parameters in SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig, to no effect.
- Also tried clearing distributed token cache, but it didn't help.

I am all out of ideas what to investigate next.

Comment: My Security Token Service Config:
```SecurityTokenServicePublicUrlSuffix : /_vti_bin/spsecuritytokenserviceactive.svc
SecurityTokenServiceMetadataPublicUrlSuffix : /_vti_bin/spsecuritytokenserviceactive.svc/mex
LocalLoginProvider : SPLocalLoginProviderName=SharePoint
TrustedLoginProviderNames : {}
TrustedLoginProviders : {}
TrustedAccessProviders : {}
TrustedSecurityTokenServices  : {}
AuthenticationPipelineClaimMappingRules : {WindowsMappingRule}
AllowMetadataOverHttp : False
UseSessionCookies : True```

Comment: `WindowsTokenLifetime : 00:30:00
FormsTokenLifetime : 00:20:00
CookieLifetime : 00:20:00
ServiceTokenLifetime : 10:00:00
MaxLogonTokenCacheItems : 250
MaxLogonTokenOptimisticCacheItems : 100000
LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow : 00:30:00
MaxServiceTokenCacheItems : 250
MaxServiceTokenOptimisticCacheItems : 100000
ServiceTokenCacheExpirationWindow : 00:10:00
ApplicationTokenLifetime : 1.12:00:00
AuthenticatorTokenLifetime : 1.12:00:00
MinApplicationTokenCacheItems : 250
MaxApplicationTokenCacheItems : 100000
ApplicationTokenCacheExpirationWindow : 00:10:00`

Comment: `LoopbackTokenLifetime : 10:00:00
AllowOAuthOverHttp : True
CookieValueHandlerType : Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSessionSecurityTokenCookieValue
NameIdentifier : 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@44cdce4e-ee50-4039-9d74-478682ede717
PidEnabled : True
HybridStsSelectionEnabled : True
Name : SecurityTokenServiceManager
TypeName : Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceManager
DisplayName : SecurityTokenServiceManager
Id : 40721f54-d352-4560-83dc-ca8b35380d02
Status : Online
Parent : SPSecurityTokenServiceName=SecurityTokenService`

Comment: `Version : 10999811
Properties : {}
Farm : SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
UpgradedPersistedProperties : {}
CanSelectForBackup : True
DiskSizeRequired : 0
CanSelectForRestore : True
CanRenameOnRestore : False`

Comment: Have you been able to reliably recreate this? I'd run Fiddler on one of the client machines to try to recreate it and see what is happening on their side. Might help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, as horrible as it may be, you might have to kick up your ULS logs to Verbose and do a deep dive.

Comment: Can you temporarily remove your load balancers from the equation completely and any proxy servers to see if you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Taylor haven't been able to recreate it myself. I just get notified after the fact via logs. Don't have access to client machines to investigate via fiddler.

I tried changing to verbose logs, but can't seem to filter out noise from the signal. What should I be looking for in there?

Comment: @TrevorSeward I have already removed the loadbalancer and shutdown all front-end servers in the farm, except one that is directly serving requests. the issue still remains unchanged.

Comment: @Hammad - Filtering is tricky, but look into ULSViewer so you can filter/colorize by Correlation ID. If you can get an approximate timeframe when it happened you can run `Merge-SPLogFile`. Just make sure you have enough disk space to accommodate the verbose logs and export file. Once you find a user session and can follow it you will hopefully get an answer.

Comment: So, I did two things:
> Clear-SPDistributedCacheItem -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache
> Set Pooling=false in sessionstateservice connection in web.config

These things made the issue go away. But it feels like I have not learned much from it. Can someone explain why/how it worked? Or if it is even the right thing to do?